# Creating my first Vue.js app with WebStorm

Tags: macos, vue.js, webstorm

I am trying to create my first app ever on Mac with WebStorm. But I am getting the following

[image: error]

I installed all the needed packages as recommended by JetBrains.

[image: packages]

Comment: share your code please ?

Comment: @C2486 as i said i cannot create an app,so there is no code yet

Comment: which version of vue-cli do you have? Maybe there is some issue with version 3^

Comment: vue@2.5.16   npm 5.6.0 vue-cli 3.0.0-rc. 3

Comment: you have chosen `vue-cli 2.9.6` as **vue cli**; try choosing `3.0.0-rc. 3` instead (likely `~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli`) - does it work? Also, can you create a new project by running `vue init webpack vapp` in terminal?

Comment: @lena when i use vue init webpack vapp i get vue: command not found

Comment: this is likely because `vue` resolves to `@vue/cli 3.0.0-rc. 3` and not to `vue-cli 2.9.6` on your system. Did you try creating a project with `~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli` per my suggestion?

Comment: the path is correct then; check where `node_modules/@vue/cli` is located in your system

Comment: @lena i reinstalled vue-cli and ~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli    gives the following error typeerror cannot read property 'proxy' of undefined

Comment: this is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32583, fixed in 2018.2. You can try [2018.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/eap/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion from my previous installation

1. First install vue-cli with with the following command

   `npm i @vue/cli -g`

The following commands generated some issues in my case:

```
npm install -g vue-cli
```

For the old version: `npm i vue-cli -g`

[To prevent permissions errors while installing vue-cli](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

- Back-up your computer before you start.
- Make a directory for global installations:
  mkdir ~/.npm-global
- Configure npm to use the new directory path:
  npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
- Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line: export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
- Back on the command line, update your system variables: source ~/.profile

2.
[Install WebStorm Early Access Program](http://Install%20WebStorm%20Early%20Access%20Program)